# Minimum Office 365 subscription to have Office on the web,SharePoint & Exchange

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, licensing, license

We need our users to have the following:-

1. Office online. NO need to download desktop apps.
2. SharePoint
3. Exchange email accounts.

so what is the minimum subscription needed? will Office 365 E1 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans works for us?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 E1 can meet your requirement.

If you want the lowest subscription, [Microsoft 365 Business Basic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/microsoft-365-business-basic?rtc=1&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) is the lowest subscription that can meet your requirement.

Here's an [article](https://www.enclyne.com/microsoft-office-365-e1-vs-business-basic-plan-comparison/) for you to know more about the difference between Microsoft Office 365 E1 and Microsoft 365 Business Basic.

Sum up, in a business of less than 300 users for the foreseeable future, the Microsoft 365 Business Basic is priced competitively and has a strong feature set for web content management. In a business of more than 300 users, the Microsoft 365 Business Basic is no longer an option for your organization. However the Microsoft Office 365 E1 still has a strong feature set in comparison to outside competitors at the same price point.

There is the [same post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/460273/minimum-office-365-subscription-to-have-office-on.html) on the Q&A Forum, I suggest you can follow the progress of the post.